# Getting Distinct Id(FK) by the latest date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, distinct

I'm currently working on a query where I need to distinct ID based on the latest date created.

Here is my diagram

```
|  ID  |    ModelID     |    LocationId   |  DateCreated  |
|------+----------------+-----------------+---------------|
|   1  |       1        |        5        |   02/03/2019  |
|   2  |       2        |      null       |   01/14/2019  |
|   3  |       2        |        0        |   02/03/2019  |
|   4  |       2        |        5        |   12/30/2018  |
|   5  |       4        |        3        |   01/10/2019  |
|   6  |       3        |        5        |   02/14/2019  |
|   7  |       2        |        5        |   03/13/2019  |
```

So my goal is to Distinct `ModelId` but still show if the `LocationId is null or equals to 0` then if `LocationId` is still the same, Get the Latest `DateCreated` and show it to the List

Desired output:

```
    |  ID  |    ModelID     |    LocationId   |  DateCreated  |
    +------+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
    |   1  |       1        |        5        |   02/03/2019  |
    |   2  |       2        |      null       |   01/14/2019  |<-still show
    |   3  |       2        |        0        |   02/03/2019  |<-still show
    |   4  |       2        |        5        |   03/13/2019  |<-The Latest
    |   5  |       4        |        3        |   01/10/2019  |
    |   6  |       3        |        5        |   02/14/2019  |
```

Here is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    a.ModelID, a.LocationId,
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         CONVERT(NVARCHAR, DateCreated, 101) 
     FROM 
         db.DeliveryDates 
     WHERE
         isDeleted = 0 
         AND DeliveryId = a.DeliveryId) AS DateCreated,
FROM 
    db.DeliveryCarInfo a
WHERE
    a.isDeleted = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try with below code

```
DECLARE @DeliveryCarInfo TABLE (id int,modelId int,locationId int null,DateCreated date)

INSERT INTO @DeliveryCarInfo
(
    id,
    modelId,
    locationId,
    DateCreated
)
VALUES
(1  ,1 ,5,'02/03/2019'),
(2  ,2 ,null,'01/14/2019'), 
(3  ,2 ,0,'02/03/2019'),
(4  ,2 ,5,'12/30/2018'),
(5  ,4 ,3,'01/10/2019'),
(6  ,3 ,5,'02/14/2019'),
(7  ,2 ,5,'03/13/2019')

Select X.Id,X.modelId,X.locationId,X.DateCreated from (SELECT *,row_number() OVER (PARTITION by modelId,locationId ORDER BY dateCreated desc)R FROM @DeliveryCarInfo

)X
WHERE X.R=1

ORDER BY X.modelId,X.DateCreated
```

Comment: Thanks sir, But its also removing the duplicate `modelId` even if its `null` and `0` it comes 2 values

Comment: Understand, have updated my query ,please use updated code

Comment: Accepted as answer, Thank you very much sir! been stucked for this code for a day and a half already! really is a life saver

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query. Union will help to get the desired result.

```
with cte
as 
(
SELECT a.ModelID 
        , a.LocationId 
        , (Select top 1 convert(nvarchar,DateCreated,101) from 
        db.DeliveryDates where isDeleted=0 and DeliveryId=a.DeliveryId) as 
         DateCreated
FROM db.DeliveryCarInfo a
WHERE a.isDeleted = 0
)
select ModelID, LocationId, DateCreated 
from cte 
where isnull(LocationId, 0) = 0

union

select ModelID, LocationId, max(DateCreated) as DateCreated
from cte
where isnull(LocationId, 0) != 0
group by ModelID, LocationId
```

Comment: sir I tried this solution but why im getting a `ModelID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` on the Group By?  it

Comment: try updated query now. I can't verify as do not have table structure and data ready.

Comment: Why is it every column in my group by is i need to call, now its looking for DateCreated

Comment: try again... please share the table structure with some sample data so that I can run the query and correct the syntax issues. All the column which you want to select either should be part of the group by or aggregate function. if we have unique records of (modelId and locationId) then we do not need group by and max function. as I assumed for location null and 0 scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT A.* from @tbl A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ModelId,Max(DateCreated) As CreateDate from @tbl Group By ModelId
) As B
    ON B.ModelId = A.ModelId
    AND A.DateCreated = B.CreateDate

 UNION 

 Select * from @tbl A
 WHERE LocationId IS NULL OR LocationId = 0
```

Comment: sir How can I apply the tables for `db.DeliveryCarInfo` and `db.DeliveryDates` in your code. sorry

Comment: Please replace this                                                                       
(From)                                                                                                          
 "SELECT ModelId,Max(DateCreated) As CreateDate from tbl Group By ModelId"                                                                                                        Replace to
" SELECT ModelId,Max(DateCreated) As CreateDate from DeliveryCarInfo DCR
INNER JOIN DeliveryDates  DD ON DCR.Id =DCR.Id Group By DCR.ModelId"            and also replace tbl  to "DeliveryCarInfo "

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT ModelID, LocationId, DateCreated FROM  (
    SELECT 
        a.ModelID, a.LocationId,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, d.DateCreated, 101) AS DateCreated,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ModelID, a.LocationId ORDER BY d.DateCreated DESC) RN
    FROM 
        db.DeliveryCarInfo a
            LEFT JOIN db.DeliveryDates d ON d.DeliveryId = a.DeliveryId AND d.isDeleted = 0 
    WHERE
        a.isDeleted = 0
) AS T WHERE RN = 1
```